# My laptop speaker doesn't work, only headphones

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

Suddenly my laptop speakers don't work, only sound come out when I plug in the headphone, I use Ubuntu 17.10.

I think it's not related to Ubuntu OS or version, because I also use windows 10 on the same machine and the problem affects both (Ubuntu & windows) so I think it's physical problem, I had searched how to fix this physical problem (which is common in iPhone and Macs), the problem is the machine thinks that you are plugging the headphone as the detector sensor in the headphone socket stuck, so it's recommended to clean it, but this solution didn't work.

when I got to sound setting only headphone device appears as output device, any help, please?

[only headphone device appears as output device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXBFm.png)

So if anyone had faced the same problem, what did you do to get sound from speakers?

If there is no solution for this, then how to make speaker and headphone woke in the same time?